# BarButton item with different behaviours

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

In my current app, I have three UIViewControllers and I am using StoryBoard:

ViewController, MenuViewController, CategoriasListViewController.

To show MenuViewController from ViewController, I am using a button action.
To go back from MenuViewController to ViewControler, I am using a BarButton item with the following action method:

```
- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

To show CategoriasListViewController from MenuViewController, I am using also a button action.
To go back from CategoriasListViewController to MenuViewControler, I am using a BarButton item with the following action method (the same as above):

```
- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But in this case, MenuViewController is not shown, the BarButton action is ignored.

I am using the customised BarButton actions instead the default Back button, because in the header background I have an image with a logo that would be overlapped by the default Back button.
Any help is welcome. Thank you.

UPDATE 1: This is my StoryBoard:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have difficulties reading your story board but I'm pretty sure that if you put a break point in your method `- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender` you will hit that break point.
I'm pretty sure the method is being call when you hit the button (unless you forgot to hook it).

The problem look like you are wrapping your `CategoriasListViewController` inside a Brand NEW Navigation controller. So when `-backButton:` get call you are talking to that new NavigationController instead of the original one that you really want to talk to.

Remove that *second* unnecessary UINavigationController and it should work.

Comment: Thank you. I have done all in another way and it is working now.